# How to get value from JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, replace

In my web application, Web API returns following JOSN object.

```
[ 
   { 
      "templateID":1,
      "template":"{\r\n  \"Body\": \"sample date hete hee. Name\"\r\n}"
   },
   { 
      "templateID":2,
      "template":"{ \"Body\": \"you soon.\" }"
   }
]
```

I need to get `Body` value from each JSON node by passing `templateID`. The problem is you can see this JSON has `\r\n` in some places.How ever I need get the Body value of each node. As an example if I pass 1 I need to get `sample date hete hee. Name` if pass 2 i need `you soon.` how can I do it?

I tried this. but its not working

```
var data2 = [ 
   { 
      "templateID":1,
      "template":"{\r\n  \"Body\": \"sample date hete hee. Name\"\r\n}"
   },
   { 
      "templateID":2,
      "template":"{ \"Body\": \"you soon.\" }"
   }
]

function usersBasedOnIDs(isShow,field){

    var filtered=data2.filter(function(item){
        return item[field] == isShow;         
    });
    console.log(filtered);
}

usersBasedOnIDs(1,'templateID');
```

Comment: `item[field] == isShow;` there no template with value `1`. so it just prints empty array

Comment: _“The problem is you can see this JSON has \r\n in some places.”_ - what does that have to do with _anything_?

Comment: Your json has json encoded within its strings. Shouldn't the whole thing just be json instead?

Comment: You’re simply looking in the wrong field. You want to check what is contained in `templateID`, but you passed `'template'` to your function to dynamically access the property …

Comment: @CodeManiac I updated it. now it returns `"{
  "Body": "sample date hete hee."
}"` How can I get `Body` value

Comment: @Adam you need to get the first element from array and parse the JSON string and then access the `Body` property

Answer (score 3):

```
item[field] == isShow;
```

You don't have any object where this condition will be true, i guess you want to filter element based on ID and then see it's body value

```js
var data2 = [{
    "templateID": 1,
    "template": "{\r\n  \"Body\": \"sample date hete hee. Name\"\r\n}"
  },
  {
    "templateID": 2,
    "template": "{ \"Body\": \"you soon.\" }"
  }
]

function usersBasedOnIDs(isShow, field) {

  var filtered = data2.filter(function(item) {
    return item[field] == isShow;
  });
  console.log(filtered && JSON.parse(filtered[0].template).Body);
}

usersBasedOnIDs(1, 'templateID');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this

```
var x = [ 
   { 
      "templateID":1,
      "template":"{\r\n  \"Body\": \"sample date hete hee. Name\"\r\n}"
   },
   { 
      "templateID":2,
      "template":"{ \"Body\": \"you soon.\" }"
   }
]
for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){
  let y = x[i].template;
  console.log(JSON.parse(y).Body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function usersBasedOnIDs(templateId) {
    let result = data2.find(function(item) {
        return item.templateId === templateId;
    });
    if(result === undefined) {
        return;
    } else {
        return JSON.parse(result.template).Body;
    }
}

console.log(usersBasedOnIDs(1));
```